# Projective Dimension of Filtered Colimit

Tags: modules, limits-colimits

Let $M_i$ be modules over a ring $R$. It's an easy exercise to show that p.dim$( \oplus_{i =1}^n M_i) = \sup \{ $p.dim$(M_i) \} $. Does projective dimension also distribute over filtered colimits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*No:* Filtered colimits of projectives comprise the flat modules, and these are not necessarily projective.